# What sort of command line is needed to find the sum of all the credit card numbers and have them organized in ascending order?

Tags: javascript

```
var cc = ['4916-2600-1804-0530', '4779-252888-3972', '4252-278893-7978', '4556-4242-9283-2260'];
```

function for summing each string

```
function highest(inputArray) {
  var currentHighest = 0;
  var largest = 0;
  var tempArray = [];
  for (var a = 0; a < inputArray.length; a++) {
    tempArray.push(inputArray[a].replace(/\D/g, ''));
  }
  function sumDigits(strA) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < strA.length; i++) {
      sum += parseInt(strA.charAt(i), 10);
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

organizing the strings in array

```
  for (var a = 0; a < tempArray.length; a++) {
    var csum = sumDigits(tempArray[a]);
    if (csum >= currentHighest) {
      currentHighest = csum;
      largest = inputArray[a];
    }
  }
  return largest;
}
    console.log(highest(cc));
```

Here at the end is where my knowledge ends. Not sure what to use to call back the data so it is organized by order and sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a hash table for the total and sort with the total of all digits.

```js
var cc = ['4916-2600-1804-0530', '4779-252888-3972', '4252-278893-7978', '4556-4242-9283-2260'],
    total = {};

cc.forEach(function (a) {
    total[a] = a.match(/\d/g).reduce(function (r, b) {
        return r + +b;
    }, 0);
});

cc.sort(function (a, b) {
    return total[a] - total[b];
});

console.log(total);
console.log(cc);
```

Comment: Impressive. What is this function called?

Comment: which one? the mapping to the hash table? or the sort callback? the pattern has no name.

Comment: The hash table. What sort of variable is needed so the console writes the mapping and callback?

Comment: the callback is a function, the hash table `total` is an object, please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to map the original array to objects with original value and sum (created by matching decimals, then reducing them to their sum) and then sorting by the sum and finally mapping back to original values...

```
var cc = ['4916-2600-1804-0530', '4779-252888-3972', '4252-278893-7978', '4556-4242-9283-2260'];

var sorted = cc.map((item, i) => ({
    val: item,
    sum: item.match(/\d/g).reduce((memo, item) => memo = memo * 1 + item * 1)
})).sort((a, b) => a.sum - b.sum).map(item => item.val)

// console.log(sorted)
// ["4916-2600-1804-0530", "4556-4242-9283-2260", "4779-252888-3972", "4252-278893-7978"]
```